# Install Firefox add-on in Linux command line

Tags: linux, firefox, debian, firefox-extensions

I start with a bare Debian 9 install with no desktop environment.

I have written a bash script that installs task-mate-desktop and xrdp. It also downloads a Firefox extension using wget. Would it be possible to install this extension in the command line?

Comment: see this: https://askubuntu.com/a/73480

Comment: @Biswa I have already tried that, I get "Error: GDK_BACKEND does not match available displays"